# calling contour without plotting it, python, pylab inline

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

For an algorithm I am using contour, but I'm only interested in its collection of paths. Since I have called

```
pylab inline
```

from the start, and it is now too painful to rewrite the code without the inline (many functions have to be declared more carefully, like np.something() instead of something(), etc...), I was wondering if there is a way to call contour without it plotting the contour map ? 
Something like

```
contour(image_matrix, 'No Show')?
```

Regards

Answer (score 4):

The following is a modified code i used to get the points on a unit circle within in a declared meshgrid. It gives the contour points faster than plt.contour and doesn't plot the points.

The matplotlib._cntr is the core function called by plt.contour which tries to get the contour points.

```
import matplotlib._cntr as cntr
import numpy as np

# Test data.
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = x**2 + y**2 - 1            # Function to get points from
# the above function can be replaced with any curve equation
# conics like ellipse or hyperbola: ((x**2)/a)+((y**2)/b)-1,etc. 


level = 0
c = cntr.Cntr(x, y, z)
nlist = c.trace(level, level, 0)
segs = nlist[:len(nlist)//2]
print segs[0][0]    # x,y coords of contour points.
```

Sorry for the poor explaination, I am not experienced enough with python. For a detailed explanation so you can refer to the link below.

*link to discussion:*
**http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/pyplot-Extract-contourset-without-plotting-td15868.html**

At the end of discussion Mr.Ian Thomas has attached a code 'contour_test.py' which may be of help to you.

*link to sample code:*
**http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/attachment/15872/0/contour_test.py**

Comment: "_cntr is not part of matplotlib any more". See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160142/how-should-cntr-should-be-imported-on-matplotlib-lts-2-2-0

Answer (score 2):

There is not specific option to suppress plotting of a [contour](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour) (as far as I can see). The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304722/python-find-contour-lines-from-matplotlib-pyplot-contour) appears to provide exactly what you want using `matplotlib._cntr`.

For your case, it may be simpler to achieve the suppression of a figure in pylab inline by switching back to a different gui, e.g. using `%pylab qt` and then call `cs = contour(image_matrix)`. This may not show anything without an explicit call to `plt.show()` and you can use `cs` to get the contour information you need.

You may also be able to use something like `matplotlib.interactive(False)` to suppress the figure.

Answer (score 1):

Because `matplotlib._cntr` is not supported anymore, you can use the `find_contour()` function from `skimage`. Here is a simple code to extract a contour level 0.8 from an analytical function from the [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html).

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure

# Construct some test data
x, y = np.ogrid[-np.pi:np.pi:100j, -np.pi:np.pi:100j]
r = np.sin(np.exp((np.sin(x)**3 + np.cos(y)**2)))

# Find contours at a constant value of 0.8
contours = measure.find_contours(r, 0.8)
```

This will give you the contour in function of (row, column) coordinates along the contour, and not the value of `x` and `y`. To convert to `x` and `y` values, you can then interpolate using `interp1d` from `scipy`:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
fx = interp1d(np.arange(0,x.shape[0]), x.flatten())
fy = interp1d(np.arange(0,y.shape[1]), y.flatten())
for contour in contours:
    contour[:,0] = fx(contour[:,0])
    contour[:,1] = fy(contour[:,1])
```

Simple code to see the results and validate:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for contour in contours:
    ax.plot(contour[:,0], contour[:,1])
fig.show()
```

[Figure of the extracted contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b24n.png)

Comment: This becomes ridiculously difficult and computation-heavy if you try to do this in irregular (inseparable) grid. Is there any way to apply `find_contour` without having to deal with transformations via interpolation? Also, it seems that `find_contour` and `matplotlib contour` result in slightly different ones, and in my cases `matplotlib contour` seems far robust. It is such a frustration that `matplotlib` discontinued `cntr` functionality...

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: You can also take a look at the [legacy contour](https://github.com/matplotlib/legacycontour)  repo.

Comment: Another option might be to define a "throwaway" figure, use `contour` on that and then define another figure on which the actual plot for displaying is defined.