# How should ._cntr should be imported on Matplotlib (LTS) 2.2.0

Tags: python, matplotlib

In order to construct GeoJson, a package uses:

```
import matplotlib._cntr as cntr
```

While using matplotlib 2.2.0 it returns

```
ImportError: No module named _cntr
```

How it should be imported?

With previous version of Matplotlib, specially 2.1.0 it works.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10709).

Answer (score 2):

This was a private module and should not have been used by third-party packages.

See https://github.com/matplotlib/legacycontour for an effort to package that code independently.

Answer (score 0):

`_cntr` is not part of matplotlib any more. I has not been used for several versions already, and I guess it now has been removed completely.

You may of course copy a version of it from a previous release (compiled for the same system) to your matplotlib folder to continue importing it as `matplotlib._cntr`.

Comment: Copying complied modules between installations is not a good idea.

Comment: @tacaswell  I know. But imagine being the user. He wants to use a package which makes use of `matplotlib._cntr`. What would you do? 1. Inform the maintainers of that package about the issue and hope that they update their package soon. But then.. 2. Get your system running again, by copying the submodule to where the package assumes it to be and continue your daily work.

Comment: Thank's @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and  Tacaswell. I'll try to implement the code, using the legacycontour as you suggested. For the usual way I'm using the previous matplotlib version.