# Extracting contours multiple times with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently using `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` to extract certain level plots form a 2D function. This is an example extracted from [here](https://mmas.github.io/conics-matplotlib), for the sake of the discussion:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['lines.color'] = 'k'
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler('color', ['k'])
x = np.linspace(-9, 9, 400)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 400)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
a = .3
plt.contour(x, y, (y**2 - 4*a*x), [0], colors='k')
plt.show()
```

I'm extracting the data from the contour for later manipulation following the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666056/matplotlib-extracting-data-from-contour-lines).

I need to do this process several times, so I wonder if there is a way to either do it without `matplotlib` or skipping the plotting stage. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody faces the same challenge, I found a suitable solution in one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376897/calling-contour-without-plotting-it-python-pylab-inline).

It uses the *marching squares method* implemented in the `scikit-image` package. As [an example](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure

# Construct some test data
x, y = np.ogrid[-np.pi:np.pi:100j, -np.pi:np.pi:100j]
r = np.sin(np.exp((np.sin(x)**3 + np.cos(y)**2)))

# Find contours at a constant value of 0.8
contours = measure.find_contours(r, 0.8)
```

There are some caveats discussed in the comments, but now you have another option to `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` if needed.