# Kernel Density Estimate on coordinates

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, scipy, kernel-density

I have used the following code after following [this tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) to perform kde on coordinates (latitudes and longitudes) that represent the positions of trees from 2015 NYC street tree census.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

xmin, xmax = min(zip_latitudes), max(zip_latitudes)
ymin, ymax = min(zip_longitudes), max(zip_longitudes)

X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([zip_latitudes, zip_longitudes])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)
```

I then plot the results which resemble a heatmap using matplotlib by doing:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax.plot(zip_latitudes, zip_longitudes, 'k.', markersize=2)
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
plt.show()
```

However, I need the coordinates in order to add them to a leaflet.js and mapbox.js plot. I tried printing some elements in `Z` but I am not sure this is right. My plan was to use python to get the coordinates then write the results to a csv the use d3 and lealet.js to create the heatmaps on a map. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I need the coordinates"*? You already have these - the `X` and `Y` arrays contain the coordinates associated with each value in `Z`.

Comment: I am trying to create an isopleth on a leaflet map. I don't think I can just plot the X, Y coordinates because this is not the same as performing kde. Therefore, I was wondering if instead of creating a matplotlib graph (which shows an isopleth), I can do this in leaflet or I could get the positions after kde which is at the lines `kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)`
`Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)` which I could then easily display on a leaflet map. Also, I have used the package leaflet.heat to obtain a heat map but I am not sure if this is the same things as kde.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by *"get the positions after kde which is at the lines `kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values) Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)`"*. `Z` is not a set of lines, it's a rectangular matrix, where the value at `Z[i, j]` corresponds to the KDE at coordinate `X[i, j], Y[i, j]`. If you want contour lines then you could first create a contour plot using matplotlib, then extract the coordinates of the lines from this (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18309914/1461210). I've never used leaflet.js before, so I don't know whether it's capable of doing this natively.